# file_get_contents php and subdirectory

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am new to php and I would like to simply read the content of a file in a subdirectory below my actuall directory.
My current directory is /var/www/drop/portal/ and my index.php is in that dir.
I have the /var/www/drop/portal/php/ dir were my paswword file si located.

here is the simple code of my "index.php" page :

```
<html>
<body>
<font size="2" face="Arial">Bienvenu sur mon outil S3</font>
<?php
define("BASEPATH"," /var/www/drop/portal/php/");
$my_filedistant_test = file_get_contents(BASEPATH."/passwd-s3fs.txt");
echo $my_filedistant_test;
?>
</body>
```

but nothing happening...

Comment: What does the error file say? Anything about file permissions? Did you consider checking the error file first?

Comment: I'd recommend you use relative paths. You know where the index.php file is, and you know where the other file is in relation to that. In PHP, you can use `__DIR__` and `realpath(__FILE__)` magic constants to get the directory that contains the file that is currently being executed, and then use that value to get at the file you want: `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/passwd-s3fs.txt');` looks like what you're after. OIf course, the user running the script must have read access to that file/directory

Comment: Probably the space before `/var`, in your BASEPATH definition.

Comment: Note: If your password file is in the document root, it may well be publicly available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I would do to check upon any errors:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

Moreover, if you are in doubt, double check by printing the path you are trying to access:

```
echo BASEPATH."/passwd-s3fs.txt"
```

just to make sure there are no typos.

Answer (score 3):

You have double slashes at parameter path in `file_get_contents` function.

**Check if allow_url_fopen is activated:**

```
<?php
    var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
?>
```

**if true go next**

I suggest to use relative base path :

```
<?php
   define("BASEPATH", getcwd() .'/php');
   $my_filedistant_test = file_get_contents(BASEPATH."/passwd-s3fs.txt");
   echo $my_filedistant_test;
?>
```

Comment: I doubt Php would care about the double slashes.  But still better to remove one.

Comment: Please assign the correct answer. So, someone which has a problem like this can see what work in this case. Thanx !